# mRpostman Output is long vector with NAs in R

Tags: r

I am getting weird output from mRpostman. I have looked at the documentation and don't know what the problem is.

```
library(mRpostman)
con <- configure_imap("imaps://imap.gmail.com",
                      username = "mygmail@gmail.com",
                      password = rstudioapi::askForPassword())
con$select_folder(name = "MAIN")

con$examine_folder()
```

I can see I have 13 emails
[image]

```
con$search_string(expr = "class", where = "SUBJECT")
```

[image]

I think the output should a vector that is max length in examine folder. I am confused at what is the problem.

Comment: This is weird. mRpostman has been working really well with my gmail account. Could you please inform your curl version using curl::curl_version()?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get mRpostman work so I ended up using the reticulate package and Python and used the imaplib package.

```
library(reticulate)
imaplib <- import("imaplib")
con = imaplib$IMAP4_SSL(ProviderIMAP)
con$login(username, password)
con$select("INBOX")
msids =con$search(NULL, Criteria)
```

Where the `con$search` here works and makes output that makes sense.